# How to set new fields default value in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have had a mongoose schema like below:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
}
```

I had some documents with these schema and after a while I've added a new field with a default value :

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    job: {type: String, default: function() { return "Job" + this.name.toLowerCase() }}
}
```

When I get the document (`findOne`), I can see the default value be set. But when I check the exact row in my database, default value is not set yet!

When I add new documents, the default value is set and everything is alright; but how can I make the old documents' default value be set in database?

Comment: The default value will be added to the new / updated  document after adding the default value in the schema

Comment: @AbderrahimSoubaiElidrissi so should I update them all once?

Comment: Try to check using a hook `prefind` for example if the field doesn't exist add the value

Answer (score 0):

Try to updated your old documents using hook :

```
 schema.post('init', function (doc) {

  if(!doc.job){
  doc.job = "Job" + doc.name.toLowerCase();
  doc.save();

 } 

});
```

Comment: and when everything been settled, I should remove it right?

Comment: Yeah, you can remove it.